# Spring Cloud Data Flow java DSL: container properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a SCDF local deployment where I want to deploy a custom docker-based sink. This sink internally consists of a java part that acts as translation wrapper between SCDF and another bit of nonjava code.

I need to be able to control

1. Name of container
2. Number of instances
3. volumes mounted to container
4. Ports mapped to container
5. Environment variables passed to the nonjava code

Looking at `LocalAppDeployer` and `DockerCommandBuilder` it seems I should be able to do (1) and (2) with something like

```
HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(AppDeployer.COUNT_PROPERTY_KEY,2);
params.put(AppDeployer.GROUP_PROPERTY_KEY,"foo");

Stream.builder(scdf)
                .name("mystream")
                .definition("file|bar")
                .create()
                .deploy(props);
```

which I expect to give me 2 containers: `foo-bar-1` and `foo-bar-2`
My question is how can I archive (3),(4) and (5)?

Comment: Hi,

I don't think SCDF `local` deployer has support for what you mentioned in (3), (4) and (5). Please feel free to create a request https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues and contribute by adding these features if you can. SCDF team would be happy to help you in any of the questions to get you started.

Comment: @IlayaperumalGopinathan thanks for your answer. Would that mean that SCDF has support for it in kubernettes deployments? If so would you mind pointing me to the documentation, I haven't been able to find it. It would be helpful so I can tie in the DSL part to whatever PR I make

Comment: Kubernetes specific logic is handled by the Spring Cloud Deployer Kubernetes module and you can find this package doing all the things related to Kubernetes: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/kubernetes . You can check the documentation for it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes

Comment: @IlayaperumalGopinathan I provided a [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/pull/201). Do you have a guestimate on when this would be released?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! We plan to have a release soon (most likely by mid next week).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future searches:
TL;DR: use `deployer.<appName>.local.docker.volume-mounts` and `deployer.<appName>s.local.docker.port-mappings`

e.g:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
 
properties.put(String.format("deployer.%s.local.docker.volume-mounts", "myApp"),"/tmp/foo:/bar");

properties.put(String.format("deployer.%s.local.docker.port-mappings", "myApp"),"9090:80");

Stream.builder(scdf).name("myStream").definition("time|log").create().deploy(properties)
```

See [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/pull/201). Thank you to the SCDF team for their help